# Spring - Passing in custom object in the constructor of another custom object

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm familiar with sending and returning data as jsons in spring, but I can't figure out how to pass in a custom object with another custom object as a parameter from the client to the REST web service.

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Person> create(@RequestBody Person person) throws BaseException {
    person.validate();
    personList.add(person);
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

The json i'm passing in:

```
{
"firstName": "john",
"lastName": "smith",
"birthDate": {
    "month": 3,
    "day": 30,
    "year": 1984
},
"gender": false
}
```

and the constructions of my objects:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, BirthDate birthDate, boolean gender) throws BaseException {
    //set values
}

public BirthDate(int month, int day, int year) throws InvalidBirthDateException {
    //set values
}
```

But this is not working, I am getting the error

> 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: why not use a set and get for the BirthDate object instead of passing in the constructor

Comment: I want my objects to be immutable if possible

Comment: The error message is saying that your request is malformed ("syntactically incorrect"), not that your business logic is wrong. Check the incoming JSON and be very sure that it's valid.

Comment: Is it maybe possible that it doe nos inject via constructor and the birthdate fields are missing? (I assume you create a Date object in the constructor)